# Ember.js mixin/object internals

Tags: javascript, ember.js, mixins

I'm trying to build a little extension for Ember that would have been set up though the helper function, like `computed/observer/on`. As far as I understand, this helper function just adds property to function object:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/2fefde66fd7a06bf1f0121c1e1bcdbb6ddbe455e/packages/ember-metal/lib/events.js#L304-L309

The question is how to find that property on `mixin` initialization. Related logic in mixin prototype [looks pretty complicated](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/a93480de60995659ef87772a6547d04d85b6eb74/packages/ember-metal/lib/mixin.js#L370) and I can't understand how exactly they retrieve properties and check if `__ember_listens/observes__` set up to do stuff with right properties.

Some easy (and efficient) way to enumerate through the properties of the object?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what sort of extension you would like to build. Its very likely that there is a way to accomplish what you want while using Ember's public APIs and not having to work with its internals (which are very complicated)

Comment: I'm building a library that would allow for attaching/detaching event-handlers automatically on `didInsert...`/`willDestroy...`, when handler would be defined as property of Component: some_prop: handle('resize', function(){})

Comment: As far as I know there's no public api for that, but I don't think I need to actually use ember internals either. It's just a mixin copying some internal routines.

Comment: Very interesting. My thought is since the mixin inherits the scope of the component, you'd be able to access the component's properties on `this` in the mixin, but if that isn't working, then I don't know if I have a solution for you

Comment: No, it's working. But to detect proper functions I need to go through all properties (and not own props, unfortunately, cause for the mixin it's in prototype scope, I guess). And my main concern is that method might be very inefficient. So I was wondering how Ember does the same...

Comment: for (var prop in this) {
      if (typeof this[prop] === 'function' && isPresent(this[prop].__external_events__)) { .... } }

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the solution, but I'm sure it would help others if you created a simple ember twiddle to demonstrate the issue. www.ember-twiddle.com.

Comment: oh, nice tool, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `Object.keys(obj)`?

Comment: Object.keys() returns own properties I think, but the property I'm looking for is inherited property.

Comment: They should be the same thing, technically. The other possible methods are hacky and not as reliable, as far as I remember.

Comment: What do you mean the same thing? There's a distinction between own properties of the object and inherited ones: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys so `keys` returns properties of mixin, not the object it's applied to.